# how to parse Scorm1.2 manifest file

Tags: android, xml-parsing, scorm

I have to parse `Scorm1.2` manifest file to get all HTML page in Scorm1.2 document.

I want to follow all the standards of SCORM1.2 in my application.

To do so there is a [imsmanifest](http://www.csh.rit.edu/~lauraw/media/imsmanifest.xml) file which I want to parse. This manifest file contains many attributes like the one which is given in the link.

My question is how to parse this document, to get all the resources attributes that also contain my html file path.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `<resources>` elements in the manifest file.  Each resource will have a number of files.

```
<resources>
 <resource identifier="resource_1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="shared/launchpage.html">
  <file href="Etiquette/Course.html"/>
  <file href="Etiquette/course.jpg"/>
  <file href="Etiquette/Distracting.html"/>
  <file href="Etiquette/distracting.jpg"/>
 </resource>
</resources>
```

Just read the XML file using any XML reader that you've used before, and take the href attributes.  There will be loads of resources on how to read any given XML file, depending on the language you're using.

Bear in mind the 'base' attribute which may be used in some other elements.  Check the SCORM 1.2 spec for more details on that -

http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-1-2-Specification?type=technical_documentation